# Rails .where syntax

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, where-clause

I'm having some trouble with a .where statement in rails. Can anybody help?

```
<% due_late = project.tasks.where(":date_due < ?", Date.today).count %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`date_due` in this context is the column name as defined in the database, not the Ruby symbol `:date_due`.

```
<% due_late = project.tasks.where("date_due < ?", Date.today).count %>
#---------------------------------^^
```

#### Update after comments

It is necessary to differentiate the table name in a `JOIN` query if both tables have the same column name:

```
# Assuming it is tasks.date_due you are testing, rather than phases.date_due
<% due_late = project.tasks.where("tasks.date_due < ?", Date.today).count %>
```

As a point of advice, rather than perform this calculation in the view .erb file, it would be better to create a method in the model which returns the value.

```
def due_late
  tasks.where("tasks.date_due < ?", Date.today).count
end
```

Called in the view as

```
<%= project.due_late %>
```

Comment: That's what I thought initially, too. But when I remove the colon I get this: "SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: date_due: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "phases" ON "tasks"."phase_id" = "phases"."id" WHERE "phases"."project_id" = 4 AND (date_due < '2012-12-10')"

Comment: @NathanHackley That is because you must have the same column in both joined tables. You need to use the table name.

Comment: thank you! where does the code go for creating the method? In the helper file? Also, how would I call on that from my view, then?

Comment: @NathanHackley It would go in the Project model.  Look at the last line I have above to call it in the view (assuming `project` is an instance of your `Project` class).